# Switcher em python com Get

Tags: python, bdd

Criei uma função em Python para me retornar um nome de um objetos.

Antes de tentar usar Switcher eu fazia varias variáveis como abaixo:

```
name_case_1 = poco("Content").child("CaseItem(Clone)")[0].offspring("CaseName")

name_case_2 = poco("Content").child("CaseItem(Clone)")[1].offspring("CaseName")

name_case_3 = poco("Content").child("CaseItem(Clone)")[2].offspring("CaseName")
```

Ai eu criei essa função:
case = 'THE TEACHER'

```
def validate_case_name(case):
switcher = {
case: 0,
case: 1,
case: 2,
}
 return poco('Content').child("CaseItem(Clone)")[switcher.get(case)].offspring("CaseName").get_text()
```

case: 0 = THE TEACHER
case: 1 = THE TESTE
case: 2 = THE CAR

Porem ele sempre retorna o que esta no [2] ou seja 'THE CAR'. Alguem saberia me dizer como eu poderia fazer pra que essa minha função verificasse se dentro do switcher tem o no "THE TEACHER"?

hoje minha assertiva está assim:

```
assert_equal(context.cases.validate_case_name(case), 'THE TEACHER', 'OK')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui mano, fiz assim:

```
def validate_case_name(context, case):
switcher = {
    "THE TEACHER": 0,
    "THE ARTIST": 1,
    "THE DRIVER": 2
}
name = context.poco("Content").child("CaseItem(Clone)")[int(switcher.get(case))].offspring("CaseName").get_text()
if name == case:
    assert_equal(name, case, 'Pass')
elif name != case:
    assert_equal(name, case, 'fail')
```

Answer (score 1):

não vai dar certo pois um dicionario não tem chaves repetidas, tente assim

```
op = {1 : 'teste',
      2 : 'outro teste',
      3 : 'mais um teste'}

escolha = 1
print(op.get(escolha))
```